# Web scraping using python example

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can someone show me the code, of lets say getting the [Recent News](https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en) from google every one 30 minutes and show them in my website using python?

I watched 44 videos tutorials and learned the basics stuff.

An example was:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# or if your're using BeautifulSoup4:
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=78').read())

for row in soup('table', {'class' : 'spad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
  tds = row('td')
  print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
  # will print date and sunrise
```

but a beginner like me cannot understand how this piece of code can help me solve the above example.

Comment: If you want to display the news, you should be using the google rss feed.  You don't need to webscrape anything, unless you're just doing it for practice.  [example](http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&output=rss)

Comment: It's just one example... I want to get the news but not from google..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a trivial example that gets all the main titles from google news in every half an hour and prints them out. As for displaying them on your website depends on how it is implemented. For example if it gets it contents from a MYSQL database, you can easily make this script to update the DB every time it downloads the new titles.

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import lxml.html as lh
import time  

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

while True:
    r = br.open('https://news.google.com/')
    html = r.read()
    doc=lh.fromstring(html)
    for i in doc.xpath('.//*[@class="esc-lead-article-title"]'):
        print i.text_content()
    time.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: But root, how would you get the source of the article as well as the title? I tried `esc-lead-article-source`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see an import statement of something you're not familiar with, it's always wise to do a quick google search. Mine yielded

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) . here you can read the documentation for a python library known as beautiful soup.

[UrlLib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) here is the library used to open a URL

Read the documentation and it should help you understand just how this little snippet can be used to your advantage :).

Comment: I could understand this code... I know that.. but instead of print it I want to add it on my website... I could do that using python? And as I know I should run the program to execute the code... So I need every 30 minute execute the program?

Comment: Find a library which allows you to publish dynamic websites, OR, use websockets. Yes you can do this with python, no you do not need to execute it every 30 minutes, you can just have it keep running, then check when the time is on the 30 minute or 00 mark. Best of luck!

Comment: @ Loclip -- please edit your question according to your comment, your question is somewhat confusing. Tell us exactly what is troubling you? Are you undable to collect the data you want and why? Are you unable to display it? Why?